# The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, apache2

Error is occurring when I am opening [www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin](http://www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin)

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at myclassbook.in Port 80

I using digitalocean server hosting services.

I have completed the installation of apache2, mysql, php and phpmyadmin.

I have also inserted a link into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and ServerName localhost into apache2.conf file.

> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

but still it is not working.

my hosts file is

> 127.0.0.1    localhost
>
> 12.23.53.342 mysite.com

my 000-default file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mcb/public
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mcb/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem will solve after Re-install phpmyadmin.

Enjoy...

Answer (score 27):

Create a symbolic from the terminal: (it works for me)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: My man, thanks very much, didn't remember of that, worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Worked for me after a long battle trying out many options from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04 that did not work and also adding the line `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to the apache2.conf with and editor `sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I can finally hit the sack. Hope it works for you thank me later :)

Answer (score 0):

delete your cookies and try again in my case it worked

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall or delete cookies, instead try changing the PHPMyAdmin port number (in URL) and just check whether it matches the port number that you have provided in the config file of Apache.

Answer (score -1):

If not

```
echo 'Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```